# Laravel returning query exception with no error message

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am doing a simple create operation. Below is the code on controller.

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg',
        'categories' => 'required',
        'sections' => 'required',
    ]);
    // try {
        $imagePath = $request->file('image')->storeAs('images/post', Carbon::now() . substr(str_replace(['.','?','/'], '-', $request->title),0,50) . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'public');
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->description = $request->description;
        $post->content = $request->content;
        $post->tags = $request->tags ?? '';
        $post->slug = substr(str_replace(['.','?','/'],'-',$request->description),0,500);
        $post->image = $imagePath;

        if ($post->save()) {
            $post->getCategories()->sync($request->categories);
            $post->getSections()->sync($request->sections);
            UtilityFunctions::createHistory('Created Post with Id ' . $post->id . ' and title ' . $post->title, 1);
            return redirect()->route('admin.posts.index')->with(['successMessage' => 'Success!! Post created']);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['errorMessage' => 'Error!! Post not created']);
        }
    // } catch (Exception $e) {
    //     return redirect()->back()->with(['errorMessage' => $e->getMessage()]);
    // }
```

It throws Illuminate\Database\QueryException but the exception has no message. It does not tell what went wrong.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXkLL.png)

Comment: Check your log file for more info about error.

Comment: I checked the log and it had something to do with invalid characters in filename. Apparently I used date time and title to name the saved image. Since the language is Devanagari, it inherited some special characters while saving image. That seemed to cause the problem. But I am wondering why it did not return any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the title part inheriting from post title while saving the imagepath. The new image now only inherits current date and time as filename and path.

```
$imagePath = $request->file('image')->storeAs('images/post', Carbon::now()  . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'public');
```

This project uses devanagari characters and seems like it had trouble saving the image path containing special characters from devanagari.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set .env credentials like below:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

And also run following command after setting them:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: Did not work. However, I removed the title while storing image and just used date time. Now it seems to work. Why it did not return any error message is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Check what you get in title using dd($request->title) at start of function I think you are getting it null.